# passing a location of build.xml in ant

Tags: linux, ant

I'm trying to run a script that uses an ANT build but I don't want to have to run it from the location where my build.xml file is. Is there a way to pass the location to ant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`-buildfile`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options) option. For e.g.

```
$ cd /some/other/directory/
$ ant -buildfile /path/to/build/file.xml
```

There are two synonymous options for this, `-file` and `-f`. Therefore you can use either of

```
$ ant -file /path/to/build/file.xml
```

or

```
$ ant -f /path/to/build/file.xml
```